# Можно ли скопировать Dom дерево для того что бы получить к нему доступ?

Tags: javascript, dom

У меня есть объект

```
obj['this'] = <div> hello World </div>
```

Есть объект Proxy который следит за изменениями в объекте.

```
const handler = {
  get: function (obj, prop) {
  return obj[prop]
},
set: function (obj, prop, value) {
  obj[prop] = value
  return obj
 }
}
 function proxy (obj) {
   obj = new Proxy(obj, handler)
 return obj
}
```

При изменении свойств вызывается сеттер
Но у меня нет доступа к контексту и я не могу получить Dom дерево

Могу ли я записать в статическое поле obj['this'] для того что бы при изменениях свойств объекта получать его оттуда и производить манипуляции с Dom объектом ?

Comment: Можете. Пишите.

Comment: понял  Dom.staticProperty = obj['this'] то что нужно. два часа искал...